# Spring Boot forcing https cause redirection too many times in Google App Engine

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, ssl

I enabled `https` for all the requests within the App Engine - Flexible Environment.

```
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    if (securityProperties.isRequireSsl) http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()
}
```

But it is causing too many redirects and fails.

How to force https with Spring Boot on App Engine?

Answer (score 2):

> The Google Cloud Load Balancer terminates all https connections, and
>   then forwards traffic to App Engine instances over http. [Read More](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/how-requests-are-handled)

Which was causing the redirects as the Spring Application was unaware of this switch.

App Engine proxies the request to the application by adding the `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-For` headers with which spring identifies the actual request protocol and where the request actually originated from.

To enable such behavior, I added the following configuration in `application.yml`:

```
server:
  tomcat:
    remote_ip_header: X-Forwarded-For
    protocol_header: X-Forwarded-Proto
```

Comment: For those who happen to have the same issue, these two keys are deprecated, use: server.tomcat.remoteip.remote-ip-header and server.tomcat.remoteip.protocol-header